# Can I insert the data to a table which columns are unknown in mdb file from c#?

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview, windows

I think I have a weird doubt!!

I have created a table using C#[with a tool not programatically ] in mdb file, then I am inserting the values to that table, what the issue is I don't know how many columns are available in that table, but I wanna insert value from the datagridview..

Spire.DataExport.Access.AccessExport accessExport = new Spire.DataExport.Access.AccessExport();

```
                    accessExport.DataSource = Spire.DataExport.Common.ExportSource.DataTable;
                    accessExport.DataTable = this.dataGridView2.DataSource as System.Data.DataTable;
                    accessExport.DatabaseName = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
                    accessExport.TableName = "ExtractedTable";
                    accessExport.SaveToFile();
                    //OleDbCommand cmdt = new OleDbCommand("Create Table "+profiletablegrid. ", con);
                     string strDirectory = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
                     OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + strDirectory);
                     conn.Open();
                     for (int i = 41; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
                     {
                         for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
                         {
                             OleDbCommand cmdd = new OleDbCommand("Insert into sample values(@a,@b,@c,@d)", conn);
                             cmdd.Parameters.Add("@a", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                             cmdd.Parameters.Add("@b", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                             cmdd.Parameters.Add("@c", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                             cmdd.Parameters.Add("@d", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                             cmdd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                         }
                     }
```

So Since I know the columns I am inserting 4 values, but if I don't know how many columns are there, then how can i insert the value...
I can count the datagridview total columns, but how can I insert according to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing `column Names` or `Number of Columns` of a `table` in my experience it's not possible to `insert` `data` in to it. How ever you can use this work around to get `column names` of particular `table` then `insert data` into those `columns`. 
The first thing you would do is make sure that no data gets `returned`:

```
SELECT TOP 0 your_table.* FROM your_table WHERE 1 = 2;
```

Now assuming you know how to set up a `DataReader` you would do the following:

```
using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    // This will return false - we don't care, we just want to make sure the schema table is there.
    reader.Read();

    var table = reader.GetSchemaTable();
    foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(column.ColumnName);
    }
}
```

Now you have column names so build up your `insert statement`.

Ok Consider you have `n` number of `columns` then your `code` will look like this.

```
List<string> colArr=new List<string>();
foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
{
    colArr.Add(column.ColumnName);
}
```

now build your sql in this way.

```
string colNames="";
string val="";
for (int i = 0; i < colArr.Count; i++)
{
   if(i!=colArr.Count-1)
   {
     colNames+=col+",";
     val+="Some Value,";
   }
   else
   {
     colNames+=col;
     val+="Some Value";
   }
}
string sqlQuery="Insert Into your_Table "+colNames+" ("+val+")";
```

Comment: This will help for one user... Actually I am developing a product, so many will use, i don't know how many columns each will have.. some may have 5 or 6, after developing a product we can't go and change the code, so as an in-built I need a query which reads the number of columns and inserts the value according to the number of column, i don't want the column name it's enough to know the number of columns

Comment: Above code inserted values to 4 columns, but how can we insert if they have 5 or 6 columns....

Comment: Is there any way to export the datagridview directly to the mdb file? I have searched many sites all they did is exporting to excel and then importing to mdb...

Comment: you can try to save your returned column names in an array. then loop through this array and build up your sql insert statement dynamically. in this way you don't need to worry about number of columns if they are increasing or decreasing.

Comment: k consider I have 6 columns and I m getting in array like, 
a[0]="p",a[1]="p1",a[2]="p2",a[3]="p3",a[4]="p4",a[5]="p5"..
Then how can give insert statement for this, 
Insert into table values("......."); 
How can I Pass all the values in one row??

Comment: i have edited my code to address this issue hope you will get some idea

Comment: The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect. it shows some error in select statement

Comment: Thanks a lot mate I got more ideas from this awesome :)

Comment: OMG!! How to remove the last comma[,] ? it's showing insert syntax error because of this

Comment: Yeah done, but still I get error for only one record, I think there no way to clear that, because at the particular record,the name is o'conner so it throws syntax error, can we avoid that record and continue with the next records?

Comment: have a look at similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747370/how-to-replace-apostrophe-with-double-apostrophe-in-string

Comment: you can use `if(val.Contains("'")){string nVal=val.Replace("'","''")}`

Comment: oh!! I am using string values, so i used ' ' for all the values.. If i add this then it will replace everything

Comment: do this before this line `val+="Some Value,";`

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are using `OleDbConnection` you can call

```
DataTable schema = connection.GetSchema("Columns");
```

to get the schema data of your Database ... in that table you will find each column of each table in the db ...

use that to build you SQL statement at runtime