# Trying to update record, keep getting this error vb.net

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, textbox, sql-update

I'm sure this question will be easy for you lot... :)
I'm simply trying to update an existing record in my database using the following:

```
    Private Sub Button12_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button12.Click

    If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        cnn.Open()
    End If

    cmd2.Connection = cnn
    cmd2.CommandText = "UPDATE HireItemRecord SET HireItemBeginDate = " & TextBox45.Text & _
     " ,HireItemEndDate = " & TextBox44.Text & _
     " ,HireItemCost = " & TextBox16.Text & _
     " ,PaymentMethod = " & TextBox17.Text & _
     " ,Staff_Id = " & TextBox19.Text & _
     " ,HireItemNotes = " & TextBox18.Text & _
     " ,HireItemReturnDate = " & TextBox43.Text & _
     "WHERE HireRecord_Id = " & TextBox13.Text

    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()

    ds1.Clear()
    daHireItemRecord.Fill(ds1, "PersonDetails")
    cnn.Close()

End Sub
```

However no matter what record is selected and whatever details are in the boxes I keep getting this same error over and over:
SqlException was unhandled
Incorrect syntax near '12'.

When there is absolutely nothing in the textboxes the error changes to:
Incorrect syntax near ','.

I'm very new to this and I just can't seem to understand why this is happening. 
Thank you very much for your help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never use string concatenation to build SQL. It leaves you open to SQL Injection attacks. Try using the [SQLCommand object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) provided in .Net. This allows you to "parameterize" your query and you don't have to worry about where to put " and '.

It will also allow you add parameters naturally without having to convert them to strings. Something like this:

```
Dim command As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table", connection)
command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int)
command.Parameters("@ID").Value = customerID
```

I stole that code from the documentation about [SQL Parameters here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx#Y500).

Comment: forgot to thank you....thanks! Got it all working. To be honest I had zero idea about this method (only been programming for 6 months or so, first time I've dealt with databases), but I can clearly see the benefit of this method. Will definitely follow your advice in future.

Answer (score 1):

So much wrong with this.

1. You need a space after each comma, not before it.
2. You should be escaping your values before using them in the query. If I put "0 WHERE 1=1 -- " in any of your text boxes, it'll trash your entire table.
3. You should ALWAYS name your form controls properly. If I sent you back to this code in a year's time and told you there was a problem with TextBox44, would you know what it means? Same goes for your variables. Sometimes it's ok to have `i`, `x` or `tbl` for a variable name, but in general they should be descriptive.

Example for #2, where I've put "'1/1/1999' WHERE 1=1 --" into TextBox45:

```
`UPDATE HireItemRecord SET HireItemBeginDate = '1/1/1999' WHERE 1=1 -- , HireItemEndDate...`
```

Everything after the `--` becomes a comment, so you get this:

```
 `UPDATE HireItemRecord SET HireItemBeginDate = '1/1/1999' WHERE 1=1`
```

Can you imagine what would happen if I executed that query? Nothing good.

You should use parameterized queries, as per the recommendations in this question: [Algorithm to avoid SQL injection on MSSQL Server from C# code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249567/algorithm-to-avoid-sql-injection-on-mssql-server-from-c-sharp-code)

Comment: thanks for your advice, I will make sure I do as you said. If only I could choose several answers as my accepted answer, all have been very informative!