# Search Function not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I have a function that gets called with a parameter called "name" now it works fine.. until i do a search with a ' in it.. so I am sending this as the name

```
Plastic & Foam 3'X5' XLT
```

When i send that it returns empty in the website (no errors) but if i send jusr `Plastic & Foam` it works fine, it comes back ok. Now in the sql part I get this when i send the query through management studio like this

```
exec sp_productSearch 'Plastic & Foam 3''X5'' XLT'

SELECT Name FROM PProducts WHERE NAME LIKE '%Plastic & Foam 3'X5' XLT'
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'X5'.
```

In C# i am sending the text list this

```
Server.HtmlEncode(txtproductname.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''"))
```

Any Ideas what I may be doing wrong?

PS: The stored procedure is simple, is something like this

```
Select Name from PProducts Where NAME LIKE '%' + @NAME  + '%' ;
```

Thank you.

Comment: allowing `'` in your search queries / database is a very bad practice (sql injection)

Comment: We need to see C# code, not SQL queries, to be able to answer this. Also, please change the title to summarize your problem. Thanks.

Comment: Please include your C# code that shows where you call the `sp_productSearch` stored procedure.  I suspect that you need to use parameters in your SQL query rather than injecting the value of the string to search directly into your stored procedure call.

Comment: Why do you `HtmlEncode` anything when it goes to a SQL Server? Are you using parameterized queries?

Comment: Please post the whole procedure so we can see if you need to use dynamic SQL at all.

Comment: The issue as mentioned in an answer below was the Server Encode, this is existing code so I am just fixing the bugs but could not see the issue, now i do.. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you already have a parameter called `@NAME`

So your stored procedure just needs to do

```
SELECT Name
FROM   PProducts
WHERE  NAME LIKE '%' + @NAME + '%'
```

Or, better, so it returns correct results in the event that any of your product names contain pattern characters such as `%` don't use `LIKE` at all and use

```
SELECT Name
FROM   PProducts
WHERE  CHARINDEX(@NAME,NAME) > 0
```

Or, even better, use Full Text Search

I presume that you are building the query string inside the stored procedure and then executing it. This is not necessary based upon what you have posted so far and is a SQL injection risk.

Also don't manually escape the `txtproductname.Text` value. Pass it in "as is" using parameters.

Answer (score 3):

You're passing `'` characters "raw" to a query in SQL? You're facing a problem called [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Please find out a solution for passing data "safely" to your SQL server. For C# you should check [eg. this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249567/algorithm-to-avoid-sql-injection-on-mssql-server-from-c-sharp-code) for closer tips.

Comment: I guess he is facing a problem called [Little Bobby Tables](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**

This last part of your questions is a little bit scary

```
Select Name from PProducts Where NAME LIKE ''%' + @NAME  + '%'''
```

I was wondering why you use so many quotes and you are possible executing SQL through string concatenation:

```
EXEC 'Select Name from PProducts Where NAME LIKE ''%' + @NAME  + '%'''
```

If that is the case then a quick/dirty way to solve it is to escape quotes twice which means something like:

```
EXEC sp_productSearch 'Plastic & Foam 3''''X5'''' XLT'
```

This statement should run without problems **but it is a really poor way to execute SQL query with user input**. Other answers cover that already.

On another note, `&` becomes `&amp;` with the call of Html Encode according to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525347%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), so be careful with that too.

Comment: Read the question. They say this query in SSMS `exec sp_productSearch 'Plastic & Foam 3''X5'' XLT'` generates this error `Incorrect syntax near 'X5'.`. No `HTMLEncode` in sight and on it's own searching for `Plastic &amp; Foam ` rather than `Plastic & Foam` would just mean potentially wrong results not a syntax error. Though I agree it seems incorrect to use it.

Comment: those exta quotes were a mistake when writing it there thanks